# How do I use CSS modules with purgecss in create-react-app?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, css-modules, craco

I want to optimize a project I have that uses bootstrap-sass, essentially importing the *necessary* bootstrap files into a sass file which then gets imported into the component with CSS Modules.

If I try to use [this approach](https://purgecss.com/guides/react.html#use-craco) with craco, it removes too much styling because the css modules messes with how classes are named. That leads to important styles being deleted.

If I try to use [this approach](https://purgecss.com/guides/react.html#run-purgecss-cli-in-postbuild) it doesn't remove anything and the file stays the same. I never used an `xxl` media specifier but its still in the final chunk.

I want to keep create-react-app and not do `npm run eject`, but all the solutions I found involve using webpack, like [this](https://purgecss.com/css_modules.html)

Is there a way to use purgecss to remove excess bootstrap code while keeping create-react-app? What other options are there to optimize my css?